# Efficient way to add large GeoJson to GoogleMap on Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geojson

I have a temperature map for some area with 3 km grid.
I.e. I have about few thousands of polygons with color.

I'm trying to show them on Google Map on android in my kotlin application.

The issue is that I need to add GeoJson layer in UI thread and it takes 8-15 seconds. I.e. all this time the application is frozen

There are a lot of old answers on StackOverflow about this issue but they all are not relevant for me:

1. They propose to decrease the json - I already create clusters from nearby squares with the same value
2. They propose to use MapView and overlays - but in the latest google map API there is no MapView and ability to add overlays in background thread

I tried:

1. map.addPolygon instead of creation of a GeoJsonLayer
2. map addOverlay with GroundOverlay

Still I have more or less the same time when UI is frozen

How can I manage this issue? Is there any way to create a map from thousands of colorful rectangles in a background thread and then show it immediately in UI thread?

Comment: This might help: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: @kalabalik As I described this is not my issue. I can prepare data in a background thread

Answer (score 2):

If you already try `addPolygon()` and `GroundOverlay` there are two possibilities left:

1. using [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay) (preferred);
2. using custom drawing over [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) or [`MapFragment`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment).

IMHO Tile Overlay is a better way due possibility of high performance [`TileProvider`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider) implementation. For example, you can create tiles for "low" zoom levels and "current" (level that should be shown to user at the beginning) zoom level and store them in array (`HashMap`, etc.) or file system path `..\zoom_level\x\y\tile.png` if there are a lot of tiles. And more "detailed" tiles you can create "on the fly" (in separate thread) when it needs to be shown, and then also store them for future using (if needed). Of course, you need custom module for fast `GeoJson` reading (something like Jackson) and rendering it to the `.png` tiles. So, seems it is possible to create `TileProvider` for your case, optimal by performance and memory consumption. You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) of [Alex Vasilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov) as first iteration.

If you choose custom drawing you should override `onDraw()` method for `MapView` or `dispatchDraw()` for `MapFragment`. like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40729016/6950238). In that case you can control all of the process, but that way is more complex for implementation.

**Update:**

You can implement action for `onCameraMove()`, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591194/6950238) answer (some tricky passing of `GoogleMap` object used there):

> ```
> public class RadarMapView extends MapView implements OnMapReadyCallback {
>
>     private OnMapReadyCallback mMapReadyCallback;
>     private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
>     private Marker mMarker;
>     private Paint mPaintRadar;
>
>     public RadarMapView(@NonNull Context context) {
>         super(context);
>         init();
>     }
>
>     public RadarMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
>         super(context, attrs);
>         init();
>     }
>
>     public RadarMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
>         super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
>         init();
>     }
>
>     public RadarMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable GoogleMapOptions options) {
>         super(context, options);
>         init();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
>         super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
>         canvas.save();
>         drawRadarOverTheMap(canvas);
>         canvas.restore();
>     }
>
>     private void drawRadarOverTheMap(Canvas canvas) {
>         if (mGoogleMap == null) {
>             return;
>         }
>
>         final float centerX = getX() + getWidth() / 2;
>         final float centerY = getY() + getHeight() / 2;
>
>         canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, 150, mPaintRadar);
>         canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, 300, mPaintRadar);
>         canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, 450, mPaintRadar);
>     }
>
>     private void init() {
>         setWillNotDraw(false);
>
>         mPaintRadar = new Paint();
>         mPaintRadar.setColor(Color.GREEN);
>         mPaintRadar.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
>         mPaintRadar.setStrokeWidth(10);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
>         mMapReadyCallback = callback;
>         super.getMapAsync(this);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
>         mGoogleMap = googleMap;
>         mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onCameraMove() {
>                 invalidate();     // NB! Exactly this line you need
>             }
>         });
>         if (mMapReadyCallback != null) {
>             mMapReadyCallback.onMapReady(googleMap);
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> ```

**Update #2:**

You can make "screenshot" (not exactly screenshot, but create image of polyigons on the bitmap) of current view of polygons and move it in `onCameraMove()` (not redraw all polygons). And then in `onCameraIdle()` create and show new full polygons view. Also, you can create bitmap slightly bigger then map screen view (for zooming  out and scrolling properly). Or you can "skip" some of the `onCameraMove()` calls (e.g. call `invalidate()` once per 3 `onCameraMove()` calls etc.).

By the way: in case of Tile Overlays moving and zooming are available "from the box". You only need to create a tricky TileProvider. There are only several tiles need to be generated for whole device screen (size of the single tile is 256x256). So, you can generate tiles for current screen, for currentZoomLevel-1, for currentZoomLevel+1 (in case of zooming) and + 2 (or 3) tiles to the left, right, top and bottom (in case of scrolling). Also you can store generated tiles for future using in some cache (HashMap, LRU, etc.). And you can generate "extra" (not currently visible) tiles in separate threads.

Comment: Thank you!
Create tiles pngs fir different zoom levels from geojson looks too much work, but I'll try the second approach!

Comment: Look good, but dispatchDraw is not called on map move, so my polygons remans on the same place while I move or zoom the map

Comment: @PavelBernshtam Please see updated answer. Briefly: you can do it by call `invalidate()` of your custom view in `public void onCameraMove()`.

Comment: Thanks, but it works very not smooth. I.e. my polygons are moving slowly (!) after the map changed location. Very not pleasant user experience ...

Comment: @PavelBernshtam Please see Update #2.

Comment: Looks like this or another way I should convert my geojson to a bitmap for different zoom levels. If there is no some library it is not simple

Comment: @PavelBernshtam Just draw on bitmap with multiple of 256 sides size, like you draw on canvas in `dispatchDraw()` and split it to squares 256x256 (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25953122/6950238) answer). And yes, it is not simple. You need really tricky `TileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to not create these few thousands of polygons one shot as this will affect time and performance but instead you can create only near polygons to shown location on the fly making use of GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener and GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener.

Edit:-
"near polygons to shown location on the fly" i mean create only polygons that the user currently see i.e within the current visible region boundaries of map :- you can get it by

```
googleMap.projection.visibleRegion.latLngBounds
```

"GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener and GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListenerwhat", I mean you have two approaches here first, you update the map with polygons within the visible boundaries when user stop scrolling the map "setOnCameraIdleListener" or the second one is the use setOnCameraMoveStartedListener to update the map with the polygons within the visible boundaries each time the user start scrolling the map.

```
 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        googleMap ?: return
        with(googleMap) {
            setMinZoomPreference(9f)
            setOnCameraIdleListener {
             // first approach user stopped scrolling so update the map with polygons within the boundaries 
            }
            setOnCameraMoveStartedListener {
             // second approach user started scrolling so update the map with polygons within the boundaries 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Explain more please, what does it mean "near polygons to shown location on the fly" and how will I use  GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener and GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener?

Comment: kindly note that i updated my answer. hope to be helpful

Comment: Got it. Not sure that it is relevant for my situation, because I start from zoom out when all polygons should be visible, but I'll try. Thank you